# Directory.getFiles exclude 0 kb Files

Tags: c#, file-io

I need to exclude files with 0 kb in size on disk when my application run the code `Directory.GetFiles ()`, this application work with Windows Server Resource Manager file and fires every 5 minutes to scan files in a specific and evaluate the contents of the files folder, but at times, when the task is active short loading the file by the user, when the user attempts to upload the file again you get an error to correct it must be restarted IIS, since the locking process the file.

therefore I need to exclude files with 0 kb in size, as are the files that do not end up even by users.

I'm working with C #

Comment: Can you not just check the file sizes?

Comment: you need to check the size of file

Comment: Yes, but when check the size interrup the loading of users file

Answer (score 1):

Use the GetFiles method from a [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) instance that return an enumeration of [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) instances. The FileInfo class has the information about the File length.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/APP_DATA"));
foreach(FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{ 
    if(fi.Length != 0)
    {
     ... process the file 
     ... fi.Name
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but this method does not interrupt the loading of user files?

Comment: Why it should? It is not clear who locks your files.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved my problem with this function:

```
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }

        //file is not locked
        return false;
    }
```

If the file is locked because the user is still uploading it to the server is